# Date validation on my custom form on frontend Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How can i validate the date field on frontend with magento default date validation class. I think it has one.

For required entry, I used **data-validate**:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('DOB (YYYY-MM-DD)') ?>" name="dob" id="dob" value="<?php echo $profileData['dob']; ?>" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Date Of Birth') ?>" class="input-text validate-date" data-validate="{required:true}">
```

and added the form validate script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//added by navin
require(['jquery','mage/mage'], function(){
    var dataForm = jQuery('#edit-form-validate');
    dataForm.mage('validation', {});

});   

</script>
```

required validation is working fine but I want to validate if the input date is in correct date format.

This also arise a question, In which file magento defines all the validation class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using **errorPlacement** function,

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
    //added by navin
    require(['jquery','mage/mage'], function(){
        var dataForm = jQuery('#edit-form-validate');
        dataForm.mage('validation', {
             errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    var errorPlacement = element;
                    console.log(element.val());
                    if (element.val()) {

                        //do your custom validation code.....
                    }
                }

        });

    });   

    </script>
```

Comment: ok I got your point.But i was searching for some class that validates date, I think there should be one don't you think so? like validate-date.

Comment: yes validate-date is used for date, you can check it from /lib/web/mage/validation.js folder.

Comment: All validation of magento frontend js is comes from validation.js file.

Comment: so how do I use it here. I added the class vadidate-date but it is not working. should i add anything else?

Comment: You have added correct class in your input. This is default class.

Comment: so why is it not working?Can you enlighten me?

Comment: i have try with same class and its display validation error if you havent enter correct input.